# The truth value of quantified statements

Tags: logic, discrete-mathematics, quantifiers, predicate-logic

I just took an exam and the following problems were asked:

> Determine the truth value of each of these statements if the domain
>   consists of all real numbers.
>
> - $\forall x \forall y \; (4-x^2 < y)$
> - $\exists x\exists y \; (4-x^2 < y)$
> - $\forall x\exists y \; (x^2 < y)$
> - $\exists x\forall y \; (x^2 < y)$

I answered True, False, True, and True respectively. Was I correct?

Comment: Putting "and" between two quantifiers does not make much sense.

Comment: Sorry about that. Didn't mean to do that.

Comment: I thought it seemed odd, but didn't want to assume anything, so I didn't change those when I added the $$ in to make the quantifiers come out properly.

Comment: @Tara: I’d have done the same, but in view of the OP’s comment I’ve gone ahead and fixed it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  Fair enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’m afraid not: $x=y=0$ is a counterexample to the first statement, $x=y=2$ shows that the second statement is true, and $y=-1$ is a counterexample to the fourth statement. The third statement is, as you say, true.

**Added:** I expect that statements with a single quantifier don’t cause much trouble, but statements with two quantifiers can be a little confusing when you’re just starting. The ones in which the two quantifiers are of the same type are easiest:

- $\forall x\forall y\,\varphi(x,y)$ says that no matter what values you give $x$ and $y$ (in the relevant universe of discourse), the statement $\varphi(x,y)$ is true of that pair of $x$ and $y$. One counterexample $-$ one bad pair of $x$ and $y$ for which $\varphi(x,y)$ **isn’t** true $-$ is enough to show that this statement is false.
- $\exists x\exists y\,\varphi(x,y)$ makes a much weaker statement: it just says that there is at least one pair of $x$ and $y$ such that $\varphi(x,y)$ is a true statement about that pair. This time one example can show that the statement is **true**.

When there’s one quantifier of each type, the order is very important. Think of it as a game: your opponent picks the first variable, and you pick the second one. Whichever of you is picking the existentially quantified variable wins if $\varphi(x,y)$ is true of the pair that you jointly pick.

- $\forall x\exists y\,\varphi(x,y)$: Your opponent can pick any value at all for $x$, and you win if you can find a value of $y$ that makes $\varphi(x,y)$ true. Note that you get to know what his choice of $x$ is **before** you choose your $y$, so your choice of $y$ can depend on his choice of $x$. For instance, $\forall x\exists y(x+y=0)$ is true, because no matter what real number $x$ your opponent picks, you can choose $y=-x$ and make $x+y=0$ true.
- $\exists x\forall y\,\varphi(x,y)$: This time your opponent picks a value for $x$ and wins if you can’t find a $y$ to make $\varphi(x,y)$ **false**, i.e., if every possible choice of $y$ makes $\varphi(x,y)$ true. For example, $\exists x\forall y(xy=0)$ is true, because your opponent can pick $x$ to be $0$, and no matter what you choose for $y$, $xy$ will indeed by $0$.

Comment: So I went 1/4? Damn it, I know better than that.

Comment: @NotoriousArab: 1/4, unless I miscounted: the third is the only one that you got right.

Comment: Oh and that makes it even worse. Damn, I felt good coming out of that test. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @NotoriousArab: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: I just went through the statements again. Wouldn't the third one be false like the forth for the same reason? Since anything squared is always positive, doesn't that make $y=-1$ a counterexample?

Comment: @NotoriousArab: No, the third is true: whatever $x$ you pick, I’ll pick $x^2+1$ for $y$, and it will be true that $x^2<y$. Thus, $\forall x\exists y(x^2<y)$. The difference is that in the third there just has to be (for each $x$) **one** $y$ that works; in the fourth **all** $y$’s have to work for some particular $x$.

Comment: @NotoriousArab: You’re welcome. Practice can’t hurt, but there are a couple of useful guidelines. I’ll add them to my answer.

Comment: That'd be great. Thanks.